# Grails 3 & relational domain mapping with Mongo

Tags: mongodb, grails, gorm-mongodb

Trying to figure out if there is a way that I can relate these two domain objects in a similar way that I would if I were connected to an Oracle db.

gradle.properties

```
grailsVersion=3.2.9
gradleWrapperVersion=2.9
gormVersion=6.1.3.RELEASE
```

build.gradle

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:mongodb:6.1.3"
compile "org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.4.2"
```

Domain objects:

```
class Store {
  Long id
  // other properties
  Long sellerId
}

class Seller {
  Long id
  // other properties
}
```

I thought to do something like this:

```
class Store {
  Long id
  // other properties
  Long sellerId
  Seller seller
  Seller getSeller {
    Seller.findById(this.sellerId)
  }
}
```

In the case above, only sellerId is persisted to Mongo since it is not marked as `embedded`.  This works great if I reference it in grails code - giving me valid values for all of the properties in `store.seller`. However, if I return a `store` from a controller, `store.seller` does not come through fully.  The response JSON for store looks like this (notice how seller ONLY has the id property):

```
{
  id: 1,
  // other properties
  seller: {
    id: 22
  }
}
```

I have also tried something like this but afterLoad never gets hit:

```
class Store {
  Long id
  // other properties
  Long sellerId
  Seller seller

  def afterLoad() {
    seller = Seller.findById(this.sellerId)
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: Your store class can just be `class Store { Seller seller }` and you would have the same effect. To customize the json response, assuming you are using json views, view the documentation: http://views.grails.org/latest/#_rendering_domain_classes. Note that really your question has nothing to do with mongodb

Comment: I fail to understand the need to store `long sellerId` instead of `Seller seller` in your domain class